# How do I suppress the "New release '12.10' available" message?

Tags: upgrade, ssh, login

When I `ssh` into my [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) box, I get this message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '12.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: <redacted>
$
```

But I don't intend to upgrade to 12.10, because Mythbuntu recommends using LTS releases only.

**How do I suppress the "New release '12.10' available" message?**  I don't want to be notified until the next LTS release is available.

I've already gone to Update Manager > Settings > Updates and selected "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For long-term support versions", but that didn't get rid of this message.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The other answers aren't quite right, but combining them put me on the right track.

`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` controls what updates you'll be notified about.  `/usr/lib/update-manager/release-upgrade-motd` generates the "update available" message.  The problem is that `release-upgrade-motd` caches the message, which means that once it's been generated, changing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` doesn't get rid of the message.

So the answer is:

1. Tell Update Manager what releases you want to be notified about.
2. `sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available` to get rid of the cached message.

---

Note: For version 13.04 (and later), the path has changed. So point **2.** to get rid of the cached message is now:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

Comment: Just for future reference, Ubuntu's update-motd is designed to refresh on login as mentioned in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/update-motd.5.html).

Comment: @JohnVrbanac, yes, but `release-upgrade-motd` maintains its own cache of its part of the motd.  That's what you have to delete manually.

Comment: This works great for me with Ubuntu 12.04! I added the following two lines to my setup script to turn off the prompts: `sudo sed '17s/.*/prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and `sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`

Answer (score 6):

That message is apart of the "Message Of The Day" (MOTD) system. If you just want to disable the update message:

**Step 1:**

Use a text editor to open "/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade"

```
sudo nano /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade
```

**Step 2:**

Comment out (put "#" in front of each line) all of the code within that file so that it looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

#if [ -x /usr/lib/update-manager/release-upgrade-motd ]; then
#    exec /usr/lib/update-manager/release-upgrade-motd
#fi
```

**Step 3:**

Logout and log back in.

**Step 4:**

Done!

That should work for both Ubuntu Server 11.10 and 12.04 LTS

Comment: This will completely disable the upgrade message.  I'd still like to be notified when a LTS release is available.  But you did point me to the correct solution, so thanks.

Comment: Woops! Sorry I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to get rid of it all together. I generally don't like a bunch of stuff showing up when I first login, so I normally just remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Try Editding /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

Change Prompt from normal to lts or never;-)

Comment: That is the current setting (I'm assuming the Update Manager GUI changed it).  It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the content of
/etc/motd

which is automatically generated by scripts in :

```
/etc/update-motd.d/
```

the one you don't like is:

```
91-release-upgrade
```

so you can delete it.

Or may be better:
edit : `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

and change : `Prompt=normal`
by : `Prompt=lts`

So you will only be warned when a new lts is released.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu version 13.04 this has changed slightly, so this will consolidate the information from various other answers and update for newer releases.

-
First solution is to modify the upgrades check configuration:

```
vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

> > Change **Prompt=normal** to:
> >     **Prompt=never**  - Never check for upgrades
> >     or
> >     **Prompt=lts**    - Only check for LTS upgrades (only if current release is LTS)

-
Alternatively, to remove the check altogether, simply delete the check:

```
rm /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade
```

---

Finally: After making one of the above changes, the message may still be displaying as the daily check is cached.
Resolve this minor hurdle by simply deleting the cached check file:

```
rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```